# Can I use "nomothetic" to refer to the calculus correctness perspective in the Tractatus?

Tags: terminology, wittgenstein, philosophy-of-law

I'm doing a comparison between the Tractatus Logico Philosophicus and the Philosophical Investications.

I want to remark the difference between the solid formal edifice built in the former, in accordance with the tautologies of logic and the necessity of complying with the classical principles, the mechanical decisions, the having a reference for each one of the constituents of the propositions and so on, AND the less solder and less austere multiperspectival scheme of the latter.

Since the adjective "nomothetic" has to do with *laws*, I would like to use it to define the tractarian approach (focused on the necessary laws of logic) but I'm not sure if it is the appropriate one. 
My sentence would be somewhat as follows:
"There is a transition, in Wittgenstein's philosophy, from an univocal and nomothetic viewpoint to a multiperspectival and more flexible one".

- Is it appopriate to define as "nomothetic" the solder, formal and austhere extensional scheme of the Tractatus?

Comment: This seems to be mostly about the definition and scope of the word 'nomothetic'. It's been a while since I read the *Tractatus*, but I don't recall that word being a word that appears in it or is common in the literature. Can you clarify how this question is to be primarily about philosophy?

Comment: Just about composition -- consider just *saying* whatever you're trying to connote with the term (formal, austere, etc.)